# frontpage in wordpress not working properly while its working perfect on preview

Tags: php, wordpress, web-deployment

I m developing wordpress site.. i created a page in that when i see it in without make it for frontpage its working fine but when i set it to frontpage some of that is not working.. visit: [this link](http://www.sherazadetravel.com)
and see bottom of page.. and see other pages bottom and menu as well...
than visit this: [this link](http://www.sherazadetravel.com/homepage-corporate-2) its working fine because not seted to frontpage..

thank you..
here is Edit: its now showing same in preview but still same problems are there.. i have updated links.. pls checkout.. you can see footer.. it only causes when i make it front page.

Comment: both pages are same on my browser

Comment: thank you for your reply.. pls goto about us page from menu and see footer.. its not showing on home page

Comment: There is no difference between both pages

Comment: can you see "Invalid or expired token" at end of front page(bottom)

Comment: Yes i can. Its problem w3 cache plugin issue i think. Deactivate that plugin and try

Comment: yes its look in both site

Comment: Try this. Add this function to your Theme functions.php

  add_filter( 'w3tc_can_print_comment', function( $w3tc_setting ) { return false; }, 10, 1 );

Comment: hi,  really sorry about it both links looking same.. i m changing link and send you proper link.. thank you

Comment: i think you are calling wrong widget on homepage

Comment: hello, i have updated both link.. pls checkout its showing same or you can see footer..?

Comment: hi please check div. i think you missed to close opend <div>

Comment: but if i dont set this page to frontpage then it works fine.. if i forgot to close div than how it works in simple page??

Answer (score 0):

Disable W3 Total Cache, while developing a website

Comment: make sure this tag ```<!-- Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: http://www.w3-edge.com/wordpress-plugins/

 Served from: www.sherazadetravel.com @ 2015-11-20 05:35:34 by W3 Total Cache -->``` is no longer on the bottom the source code

Answer (score 0):

its both same in my browser but you still prblem then remove wp-catch or wp-super-catch plugin or other simulare to catch store plugin and remove all coockies and history of your browser after open this link

Comment: see first and second link now.. second link showing footer but home page doesn't.. its happening when i make it for front page.. otherwise it working fine

Comment: is prblm Caching pluging if you any catching plugin then remove and try this and otherwise reinstall this plugin or update if old version of plugin in istore your token in databse

Comment: but if i dont make this page for front page than its working fine.. the problem occurs when make it frontpage only.. the second link that working nice .. if i make it frontpage than it will not work.. also there is a portion in middle-right of page saying "what client say" it is slider.. slider not showing in front page just like footer not showing

Comment: ok then you will try create manual home page and add this template in home page and say what happen..?

Comment: and if u link my support like give like my ans and comment:-)

Comment: sorry.. didn't understand .. can you explain about create home page manually...and add template